# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: sudo

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm exploring sqlite3 in python by adding values of `ps -a` in DB. However, Im getting the no such column: sudo error from my `insert_sensor_reading()` funtion.

I've tagged the entire code just in case if anyone wants to cross verify

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
import subprocess

dbConn = None

#create table Reading
def create_table_reading():
    dbConn.execute('''CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE
        (PID            INT            NOT NULL,
         CMD            TEXT           NOT NULL);''')
    print "Created";

#Insert sensor reading
def insert_sensor_reading():   
    for i in range(0,l):
        query =  "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (PID,CMD) \
                  VALUES (" + pidstr[i] +  ","+ cmdstr[i] +");"
        i = i + 1
        dbConn.execute(query)
        dbConn.commit()
        print "inserted";

#read from table
def select_sensor_reading():
    query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;"
    cursor = dbConn.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        print "PID = ", row[0],"\n"
    print "read";

#read from shell
def read_from_shell():
    pid = subprocess.check_output("ps -a | awk '{print $1}'", shell =True)
    cmd = subprocess.check_output("ps -a | awk '{print $4}'", shell =True)

    pidstr = pid.splitlines( )
    cmdstr = cmd.splitlines()
    global pidstr,cmdstr,l
    pidstr = pidstr[1:]
    cmdstr = cmdstr[1:]
    l=len(pidstr)


#Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    dbConn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    print "Opened database successfully";
    read_from_shell()
    create_table_reading()
    insert_sensor_reading()
    select_sensor_reading()
```

EDIT:
Below is the output of `ps -a` Im storing all the PID values in pidstr and all commands in cmdstr. the error is probably because of some error while storing sudo in cmdstr but Im not sure why is it happening.

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13280 pts/18   00:00:00 sudo
13281 pts/18   00:00:00 su
13282 pts/18   00:00:00 bash
17482 pts/17   00:00:00 ssh
19635 pts/19   00:00:00 ssh
24531 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
24538 pts/1    00:00:00 su
24539 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

Comment: What exactly is the content of pidstr and cmdstr when used inside insert_sensor_reading()?

Comment: I'm running the ps -a command, pidstr is the list of PID's of all the running processes, cmdstr is all the commands

Comment: Yes, I was interested in what the actual output was, to be honest. The unknown column sudo is VERY likely to be coming from cmdstr. But I guess I figured it out.

Comment: What happens if the process list changes between your `ps -a | awk` calls? Then everything is out of sync. Is there a reason you don't just parse the output of `ps -a` in one piece?

Comment: Besides, using `global` in the way you do it is very VERY bad.

Comment: On a real side note: Your for loop in the insert_sensor_reading function is pretty much useless. If you wish to insert multiple rows at the same time, have a look at the [executemany](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) method

Comment: Thanks @shmee Im real new to python and I make changes as per the errors I get, give me some more pointers if any so I can work on it.

Comment: @glglgl thanks for pointing that out mate, im still a noob, can you tell me what would the best way be to use global or any alternative that allows the variable to get recognized in other functions as well?

Comment: @AbhayNayak As you would do it in opther languages, and as you will learn in any tutorial: by having the functions producing a value return it and by having functions using or consuming a value get it via a parameter.

Comment: duely noted. Thanks :) @glglgl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table row CMD is defined as datatype TEXT. However, in your insert statement you actually pass sth like:

`INSERT INTO MYTABLE (PID,CMD) VALUES (5, sudo)`

while it needs to be

`INSERT INTO MYTABLE (PID,CMD) VALUES (5, 'sudo')`

```
# DO NOT DO IT LIKE THIS, SEE BELOW
query =  "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (PID,CMD) \
              VALUES (" + pidstr[i] +  ",'"+ cmdstr[i] +"');"
```

**IMPORTANT**: interpolating the query strings yourself is **NOT recommended** for security reasons. Rather use the execute method accordingly:

```
dbConn.execute("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (PID,CMD) VALUES (?, ?)", (pidstr[i], cmdstr[i]))
```

Comment: Your side note is very true. IMHO it shouldn't be a side note, but a very big red flag.

Comment: dayyum, that was such a silly mistake, thank you @shmee and yes I'll look for the security aspect as well :)

Comment: @glglgl You do have a point there. I edited my answer accordingly.